# How to present partial view in jQuery dialog without navigating to another page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, jquery-dialog

I have two controllers, A and B. A is responsible for representing some data in a grid view. Assume I have a button called "ShowInfo" which brings additional info about the selected record. And to retrieve the info about the selected record is the job of controller B.

The info is so little that it'd take just a tiny place in the corner if I navigate to another view. So I thought I'd rather bring that info inside a jQuery dialog without navigating to anywhere. But I'm a bit confused as to how to do it.

Here's the action method in controller B that is responsible for providing that info in a partial view.

```
 public class BController:Controller{

     public ActionResult GetInfo(int recordID){
        RecordInfo info=RecordsRepository.GetRecordInfoById(recordID);
        return PartialView(viewName:"RecordInfo",model:info);
     }
 }
```

I don't know, maybe the action method needs to different. Maybe I should return JSON instead of Partial view, but anyway, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery `.get` or `.load` methods. For example, to replace the contents of `<div id="SomeElement"></div>` with the partial view returned by `GetInfo()`

```
$('#ShowInfo').click(function() {
  var url = '@Url.Action("GetInfo", "B")';
  var ID = someValue; // the value to pass to the GetInfo method
  $.get(url, { recordID: ID }, function(data) {
    $('#someElement').html(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery ajax to achieve this. 
Wrtire jquery ajax on the view page and call the partial view action from ajax. 
receive the result in html format and replace it in the dialog box.

Put following code on main view page(ShowInfo button page)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ShowInfo").on("click",function(){ ///give id to showinfo button and attr data-id is record id
            var id=$(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "B/GetInfo",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ recordID: id }),  
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html)
                            {
                                ////put the html response in dialog box
                            }

                });
        })

    });
```

Comment: Could you please extend on the answer. Which view do you mean? How do I call that action method via ajax? "@Url.Action('GetInfo','B')" ?

Comment: Edited the previous answer check it.